# YAML comments in multi-line strings

Tags: yaml

Does YAML support comments in multi-line strings?

I'm trying to do things like this, but the validator is throwing errors:

```
key:
  #comment
  value
  #comment
  value
  value     #comments here don't work either
```

Comment: c.f. https://riptutorial.com/yaml/example/13764/comments for some good examples and clarification.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

No. Per the [YAML 1.2 spec](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2767100) "Comments must not appear inside scalars".  Which is exactly the case here.  There's no way in YAML to escape the octothorpe symbol (`#`) so within a multi-line string there's no way to disambiguate the comment from the raw string value.

You can however interleave comments within a collection.  For example, if you really needed to, you could break your string into a sequence of strings one per line:

```
key: #comment
  - value line 1
  #comment
  - value line 2
  #comment
  - value line 3
```

Should work...